# Android .doc .pdf viewer and writer

Tags: android, pdf, docx, doc

I have some further functionality i have to implement in my app. The app must download an assessment form from a server and store it on the phone.
The user must open the form, fill in the answers to the questions and then send it back to the server.
How it is send back to the server doesn't really matter at this point but could be emailed or sent to a webservice on the server.

The problem is i'm not sure what is available to Android for opening,reading and amending either .pdf or .doc.

I have looked at the iText library for Android but apparently you can not use it to open pdfs.

What would be the best approach, file format and library to use in order to achieve the above.

Thanks in advance,

Matt

Comment: Sending people to a web-based form is out of the question?

Comment: @KenWolf My company is in the Care industry and has over 200 customer companies. Each customer company has it's own questionaire that has been endorsed by their local authority. So basically there will be 200 different forms. So no generic one. I want each company to host the doc in either pdf or doc format and i'll read it into the app for them to answer and send back

Comment: Thanks for answering - darn, I thought going web-based was the solution but sounds like this doesn't fit your requirements. It would certainly be a lot easier/cleaner. Document/PDF editing on Android (in fact, on any OS really) is not going to be easy. Think of the formatting issues! Sorry that's not much help. Hopefully someone else will have a better solution.

Comment: @KenWolf ok thanks Ken. Yes i can see this is going to be painfull.

Comment: "I have looked at the iText library for Android but apparently you can not use it to open pdfs" -- it certainly can for Java. It cannot *display* a PDF, but it can open and read it.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes sorry that's what I meant really, it can't display a pdf. Could i pick your brains Mark. How would you tackle this? The company I work for is in the care industry and the software they sell is a rostering system with electric call monitoring. At the moment when there is a new client, a care supervisor must go to the house and do a risk assessment(paper-based). They then return to the office and fill in the same form electronically, this is attached to the client's details as a pdf. There are 200 companies which all have different assessment forms.

Comment: My company wants a way of downloading the form to a tablet, allowing the supervisor to fill it in on site and send it to the server. How would you do this? If you could point me in the correct direction eg which file format, a library and the basic mechanism you would choose to do this. I'd just like some confirmation on what is the best way of doing this. Thanks in advance. Matt

Comment: @CommonsWare I've just spoken to the director and the assessment form can be in any format as Crystal Reports is used to generate it. The the form could be pdf, doc etc. So i'm not just limited to .pdf as it turns out.

Comment: One would hope that Crystal Reports would support some sort of HTML option. Lacking that, either you're hoping somebody has a PDF rendering library with form-filling capability (that doesn't cost seven figures to license), delegating the work to a PDF app (and then figuring out how to collect the results), or not using PDF on the client. I think iText can fill in a form (not 100% sure), but would need custom engineering per client for native Android interface to collect data to then merge into the form. IOW, PDF is neither cheap nor easy.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ok i'll forget the pdf route. I can get Crystal Reports to save the file as html. I've done this now and displayed the file in an Android WebView. Is there a way of editing the html in the webview and sending it back to the server? Kind of using the original file as an editable template, filling it in and submitting it?

Comment: "Is there a way of editing the html in the webview and sending it back to the server?" -- that's a question for whoever makes Crystal Reports nowadays. Android would be no different in this respect than would any other Web browser.

Comment: @CommonsWare  ah sorry I don't mean send html back to some crystal report api. I mean is it possible to load a html file into a webview for editing. Once edited I could send the edited html file back to a web service that I have created. Hope that is clearer. I basically just want to view and edit a html file. Thanks

Comment: I guess I have no idea what you mean by "editing".

Comment: @CommonsWare  for example, I have a html file with 2 questions and 2 boxes. The answer to each question goes in each box. Is it possible to load the html file on to an android device and allow the user to enter something into the box before sending the html back to server. I know I could createa custom view to replicate the html file but like i said there are over 200 different html files for each company.

Comment: @turtleboy: "Is it possible to load the html file on to an android device and allow the user to enter something into the box" -- that is what `WebView` is for. "before sending the html back to server" -- you don't send "the html back to the server". After all, the HTML has not changed. If you are unfamiliar with how Web browsers work, you will need to learn Web development before you will be able to successfully use Web-based Crystal Reports, I imagine.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am familiar with how web browsers work. I don't think i'm explaining myself correctly. I don't want to use the HTML file in the usual way where there will be boxes to enter info and the info is then 'http posted' to some web service on the server. I have chosen HTML because that was just one format available in Crystal Reports. The file format could be seen as a Bitmap for example. The boxes on the file are not mapped to fields on the server. I just want the image of the assessment form manipulated as it is only ever going to read by humans, not placed in some DB

Comment: I've found the following at Apache. Would this be a good approach? Generate a .docx file in Crystal Reports and host it on the customer's server. The app then downloads the file and edits it using the Apache POI library. Save the file(assessment form) with the user's answers and send back to the server. https://poi.apache.org/